# Question about cosmosDb Use y a mvc project architecture

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

This is my first post on stackoverflow.  Actualy, I have an MVC project with:

- MVC presentation layer
- API that serve the logic
- SQL server Database

I'm moving to a serverless architecture using:

- Preserve the MVC presentation layer
- Use azure function instead of api
- Use CosmosDb as database

My first cuestions is:

- Is correcto to dispense with the API while it's the principal component that contains the core of my application.

And the second question is:
CosmosDb can monitor a container and use trigger to connect to the azure function to acomplish some action, that mean that an Element should be inserted before calling tha logic contained in the azure function, and the question is:

- Who should insert the elemnt inside CosmosDb, could be an other Azure function?, in this case It should be called from the MVC layer ?
- The other approach is, preserving the API, and doing all call from the API, it could be correct to do that?

Thank a lot in advance
BR

Comment: This question is too broad and also opinion based. Questions need to be more focused.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.